# Filtering a list of values by a field value in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

So I'm doing some tests with GraphQL, and I'm failing in doing something that I believe is fairly simple.

When going to the GraphQL demo site (https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql) I'm presented with a default query which goes like this:

```
{
  allFilms  {
    films {
      title,
      director,
      releaseDate
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected and returns a list of films.

Now - I would like to modify this query to return only the films where the director is George Lucas, and for the life of me - I can't figure out how to do that.

I've tried using the `where` and `filter` expressions, and also change the second line to `films: (director: "George Lucas")` but keep getting error messages.

What's the correct syntax for doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the docs of the provided GraphQL schema, you'll see that this is not possible. Following is the definition of the `allFilms` field:

```graphql
allFilms(
    after: String
    first: Int
    before: String
    last: Int
): FilmsConnection
```

As per the doc, it has 4 input arguments, which are `after`, `first`, `before`, and `last`. There is no way to filter this out using the director's name.

GraphQL is not SQL. You cannot use expressions like `WHERE` or `FILTER` in GraphQL. The schema is already defined and the filters are pre-defined too. If the schema does not allow you to filter values using a certain field, you just can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can to see the graphql schema here https://github.com/graphql/swapi-graphql/blob/master/schema.graphql

The **allFilms** query does not contain a filter for the field **director**. Also i can't find other query with this filter.

Most likely you need to write a filter on the result of the query.